# How to reference a column by name in slick plain SQL?

Tags: scala, scalaquery, slick

I would like to use named references instead of positional in GetResult, so that instead of this:

```
implicit val getCoffeeResult = GetResult(r => Coffee(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
```

i could write something like this:

```
implicit val getCoffeeResult = GetResult(r => Coffee(r.get("name"), r.get("supID"),r.get("price")))
```

*I can has named result?*

Answer (score 3):

You can get it through the resultset:

```
r.rs.getString("name")
```

Comment: How weird... just changing from r.nextString to r.rs.getString("name") i get "GC overhead limit exceeded"