# Populate case class slick by column names in Plain SQL

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Using [Slick's plain SQL](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html#result-sets), I am pulling out case classes using getResult.

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: String)

def foos(): Future[Vector[Foo]] ={
  val getFoo = GetResult(r => Foo(r.<<, r.<<))
  sql"SELECT a, b FROM foo"
    .as(GetFoo)   // could also use getFoo as an implicit and use .as(Foo)
}
```

For long case-classes this quickly becomes unwieldy... Can I pass a name of the columns rather than use `r.>>` or `r.nextString` etc?

---

With [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Executing-SQL-queries)  I would do something like this:

```scala
val parser: RowParser[Foo] = Macro.parser[Foo]("a", "b")
/* Generated as:
get[String]("a") ~ get[String]("b") map {
  case a ~ b => Foo(a, b)
}
*/

def foos(): List[Foo] ={
  SQL("SELECT a, b FROM foo")
    .as(parser.*)
}
```

---

[This question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15452732/1240268) suggests you can use `r.rs.getString("a")`. This seems slightly strange and is very verbose (but it's what we're currently doing in a few places as a workaround).

Is there a better way? Or a macro that can expand into `.rs` solution?